# Back button in ajaxavailabilitycalendar.com

Tags: javascript, php, html, reload

I use the calendar on ajaxavailabilitycalendar.com. There is a demo on their site: http://www.ajaxavailabilitycalendar.com/demo
But there's an issue with the back button of the browser and the script / page which i'm explaining via that demo:
The calendar has 3 'rooms': country cottage, town flat and cave. So you see the availability of every room. But when i click on the back button of the browser (after selecting a few rooms), the same page is reloaded with the wrong availability compared with the room in the dropdown. It happens in Firefox, IE. Not in Chrome because that browser goes the 'real' previous page.
Any advice to fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried tens of scripts but came up with a solution to put the dropdown on display-none and make 3 seperate pages linking to the right room.